# "Missing list of packages to add to your project" error while install Heroku deploy plugin

Tags: heroku, command-line-interface, jhipster, hadoop-yarn

I want deploy my JHipster application to Heroku, but when I run command "jhipster heroku", I received the following error:

> Installing Heroku CLI deployment plugin
>   × { Error: Command failed: heroku plugins:install heroku-cli-deploy --force
>   Installing plugin java... yarn add v1.12.3
>   Installing plugin java... [1/4] Resolving packages...Installing plugin java... [2/4] Fetching packages...Installing plugin java... [3/4] Linking dependencies...Installing plugin java... [4/4] Building fresh packages...Installing plugin java... success Saved 1 n
>   ew dependency.Installing plugin java... info Direct dependenciesInstalling plugin java... └─ @heroku-cli/plugin-java@3.0.1Installing plugin java... Done in 2.97s.Installing plugin java... installed v3.0.1
>   Installing plugin --force... yarn add v1.12.3
>   Installing plugin --force... info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.Installing plugin --force... !
>   error Missing list of packages to add to your project.
>   Error: yarn add --force@latest --non-interactive --mutex=file:C:/Users/start/AppData/Local/heroku/yarn.lock --preferred-cache-folder=C:/Users/start/AppData/Local/heroku/yarn --check-files --registry=https://registry.npmjs.org exited with code 1
>       at ChildProcess.forked.on (C:/Program Files/heroku/client/node_modules/@oclif/plugin-plugins/lib/yarn.js:31:28)

```
at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:275:12)
at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
```

> killed: false,
>     code: 1,
>     signal: null,
>     cmd: 'heroku plugins:install heroku-cli-deploy --force' }

**Versions of tools:**

- JHipster: 5.1.0
- Heroku: heroku/7.19.4 win32-x64 node-v11.3.0
- Yarn: 1.7.0
- Node: v8.10.0

I've already tried out the following commands:

```
heroku plugins:install java - successfully installed

heroku plugins:install heroku-cli-deploy --force -
```

Then an error occurs:

> Installing plugin java... installed v3.0.1
>
> error Missing list of packages to add to your project.
>   Installing plugin --force... !
>
> Error: yarn add --force@latest --non-interactive --mutex=file:C:/Users/start/AppData/Local/heroku/yarn.lock --preferred-cache-folder=C:/Users/start/AppData/Local/heroku/yarn --check-files --registry=https://registry.npmjs.org exited with code 1
>       at ChildProcess.forked.on (C:/Program Files/heroku/client/node_modules/@oclif/plugin-plugins/lib/yarn.js:31:28)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Yarn add raise error Missing list of packages to add to your project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64131790/yarn-add-raise-error-missing-list-of-packages-to-add-to-your-project)